# how to wait for first command to finish?

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a script in bash, which is calling two bash scripts internally. Where first script includes different tests which runs in background and second script print results of first script.

When I run these two scripts one after other, sometimes, second script get executed before first script ends Which prints wrong results.

I am running both scripts with source command. Any better suggestions?

```
source ../../st_new.sh -basedir $STRESS_PATH -instances $INSTANCES 
source ../../results.sh
```

Comment: Do you really have to source the files, or can you run them in sub-shell, using `../../st_new.sh ...`?

Comment: not really, I can run them in sub-shell as well, but that will help me?

Comment: Can you give us the contents of `st_new.sh`

Comment: Normally, before the first script ends, 2nd script should not start on its own. If it is starting, then it's likely, that 1st script is forking itself to run as background task. (somewhat like `$0 "$@" &`..)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Shell scripts, no matter how they are executed, execute one command after the other. So your code will execute `results.sh` after the last command of `st_new.sh` has finished.

Now there is a special command which messes this up: `&`

```
cmd &
```

means: "Start a new background process and execute `cmd` in it. After starting the background process, immediately continue with the next command in the script."

That means `&` doesn't wait for `cmd` to do it's work. My guess is that `st_new.sh` contains such a command. If that is the case, then you need to  modify the script:

```
cmd &
BACK_PID=$!
```

This puts the process ID (PID) of the new background process in the variable `BACK_PID`. You can then wait for it to end:

```
while kill -0 $BACK_PID ; do
    echo "Process is still active..."
    sleep 1
    # You can add a timeout here if you want
done
```

or, if you don't want any special handling/output simply

```
wait $BACK_PID
```

Note that some programs automatically start a background process when you run them, even if you omit the `&`. Check the documentation, they often have an option to write their PID to a file or you can run them in the foreground with an option and then use the shell's `&` command instead to get the PID.

Comment: I have a similar issue. 
start /wait  "$(pwd)\Tools\mybat.bat"
I try to execute this command, but git bash does not wait for the bat completion. Any suggestions?

Comment: can we use: wait $!; instead?

Comment: @walknotes: You could but eventually someone will insert an innocent `echo "Waiting for PID $!"` and after that `$!` will be the PID of echo ... or not, when `echo` is a shell builtin. That can mean the script behaves differently on different shells. Rule of thumb: If you need an automatic variable, make a copy.

Comment: Strangely I couldn't get the process/command to wait with `wait $BACK_PID`. The `while` loop worked, though.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that st_new.sh does something at the end what you can recognize (like touch /tmp/st_new.tmp when you remove the file first and always start one instance of st_new.sh).
Then make a polling loop. First sleep the normal time you think you should wait,
and wait short time in every loop.
This will result in something like

```
max_retry=20
retry=0
sleep 10 # Minimum time for st_new.sh to finish
while [ ${retry} -lt ${max_retry} ]; do
   if [ -f /tmp/st_new.tmp ]; then
      break # call results.sh outside loop
   else
      (( retry = retry + 1 ))
      sleep 1
   fi
done
if [ -f /tmp/st_new.tmp ]; then
   source ../../results.sh 
   rm -f /tmp/st_new.tmp
else
   echo Something wrong with st_new.sh
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Simpler solution would be to use && instead of &. In your case you could do

```
source ../../st_new.sh -basedir $STRESS_PATH -instances $INSTANCES &&
source ../../results.sh
```