# Run command in new background tmux window and wait for process to finish

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm trying to use tmux in a script, so that it runs a command that takes some time (let's say 'ping -c 5 8.8.8.8', for example) in a new hidden pane, while blocking the current script itself until the ping ends.

<s>By "hidden pane", I mean running the command in a new pane that would be sent in background, and is still accessible by switching panes in order to monitor and/or interact with it (not necessarily ping).</s>
(cf. EDIT)

Here is some pseudo bash code to show more clearly what I'm trying to do:

```
echo "Waiting for ping to finish..."
echo "Ctrl-b + p to switch pane and see running process"

tmux new-window -d 'ping -c 5 8.8.8.8' # run command in new "background" window
tmux wait-for                          # display "Done!" only when ping command has finished

echo "Done!"
```

I know the tmux commands here don't really have any sense like this, but this is just to illustrate.

I've looked at different solutions in order to either send a command in background, or wait until a process has finished in an other pane, but I still haven't found a way to do both correctly.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Nicholas Marriott for pointing out the `-d` option exists when creating a new window to avoid switching to it automatically. Now the only issue is to block the main script until the command ends.

I tried the following, hoping it would work, but it doesn't either (the script doesn't resume).

```
tmux new-window -d 'ping -c 5 8.8.8.8; tmux wait -S ping' &
tmux wait $!
```

Maybe there is a way by playing with processes (using `fg`,`bg`...), but I still haven't figured it out.

Similar questions:
[1] [Make tmux block until programs complete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137426/make-tmux-block-until-program-completes)
[2] [Bash - executing blocking scripts in tmux](https://superuser.com/questions/1234811/bash-executing-blocking-script-in-tmux)
[3] [How do you hide a tmux pane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145857/how-do-you-hide-a-tmux-pane)
[4] [how to wait for first command to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889074/how-to-wait-for-first-command-to-finish)

Comment: any reason you cannot use the same tmux window of the running script?

Comment: Basically, I need as little output data as possible and the command has a lot of it and can also be interacted with. So it's impossible to redirect stdout to a file and watch it since I couldn't interact with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `wait-for` but you need to give it a channel and signal that channel when your process is done, something like:

```
tmux neww -d 'ping blah; tmux wait -S ping'
tmux wait ping
echo done
```

If you think you might run the script several times in parallel, I suggest making a channel name using `mktemp` or similar (and removing the file when `wait-for` returns).

`wait-for` can't automatically wait for stuff like pane or windows exiting, silence in a pane, and so on, but I would like to see that implemented at some point.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `-d` option for `new-window`, I didn't even see it while browsing the man. I edited my question accordingly and added some more ideas for the script blocking part.

Comment: I don't get it, you picked up on `-d` but didn't read the rest of my answer? Where did you get `wait $!` from? The whole point of `tmux wait ping` is to block until you signal with `tmux wait -S ping`...

Comment: Woops, all my apologies, I thought your command didn't work, but I did a massive typo and ended up searching other solutions (cf. 4th link I posted). In the end, your solution is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!

Comment: I noticed that if something goes wrong and "tmux wait -S ping" doesn't take effect there is no way to exit "tmux wait ping" with a normal Ctrl+C. Is there a way to interrupt "tmux wait" from a terminal?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are only working if you're already within a tmux session.
But if you are outside of it you've to use something like this:

```
tmux new-session -d 'vi /etc/passwd' \; split-window -d 'vi /etc/group' \; attach
```

If you want to call this within a script you should check whether or not "$TMUX" is set. (Or just unset to force a nested tmux window).

```
#!/bin/sh
export com1="vi /etc/passwd"
export com2="vi /etc/group"
if [ -z $TMUX ]
then
    export doNewSession="new-session -d 'exit 0'"
else
    export doNewSession=""
fi
tmux $doNewSession \; split-window -d $com1 \; split-window -d $com2 \; attach;
[ -z $TMUX ] && exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to make a named pipe and then wait for input using `read`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh 

rm -f /wait
mkfifo /wait

tmux new-window -d '/bin/sh -c "ping -c 5 8.8.8.8; echo . > /wait"'

read -t 10 WAIT <>/wait

[ -z "$WAIT" ] && 
  echo 'The operation failed to complete within 10 seconds.' ||
  echo 'Operation completed successfully.'
```

I like this approach because you can set a timeout and, if you wanted, you could extend this further with other `tmux` controls to kill the ongoing process if it doesn't end the way you want.